# How to store String[ ][ ] in google-cloud datastore

Tags: java, arrays, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a `String[][]` I need to store in `google-cloud-datastore`.

`Google-cloud-datastore` does not support multidimensional arrays or ArrayLists.
It does also not support `FileOutputStream` or `ObjectOutputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not clear on what you are trying to store with multi-dimensional arrays, since you are asking for Streams, perhaps you could use a Blob data type. This means, you can serialize an object and store the resulting bytes to a field of type Blob.

Comment: If I need to serialize it and store it in a blob, how do I do so?

Comment: What I mean to say. is that I've tried serializing with gson, json, tried storing it as a blob, but have had no success. I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: You might want to share some code so we can take a look at it and advise further.

Answer (score 0):

Like Sai said you could store it as a Blob. But you wouldn't be able to query it.
Would it be possible to convert the data to a hashmap or does it need to be a 2d-array?

If you don't need to query it I'd just go for the blob.